# Second-Order Taylor Expansion of Wasserstein Metric and Related Metrics

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, st.statistics, probability-distributions, geometric-measure-theory, optimal-transportation

Suppose that we have a parametric distribution $P_{\theta}$, which is indexed by the parameter $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $W\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ be the Wasserstein Metric between two distributions.

What is the second-order expansion of $W\{P_{\theta+\Delta \theta}, P_{\theta}\}$ in terms of $\Delta \theta$ and the density of $P_{\theta}$? Moreover, what about the expansion of more general integral probability metrics (IPMs), for example, Dudley metric and Maximum Mean Discrepancy?

Comment: You have to be more specific about what kinds of IPM you have in mind.

Comment: @Henry.L For example, Dudley metric and Maximum Mean Discrepancy.

Comment: Gigli has a Memoir of the AMS on second order calculus for W_2. It aims more at differential geometry, but might be relevant.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Thanks a lot for the pointer!